# Ethereum Pending Transaction

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

I am trying to send a transaction.

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(5, "ether")})

eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(5, "ether")})
```

> INFO [08-25|21:14:21] Submitted transaction
>   fullhash=0xe1b58ddcb6d8c3f3a8308e0eb275f10c0c3b7bd8807cd24ff6a315a3917ab2a5
>   recipient=0x939f34bc9253a62927871c889bcf62f398d264a6 INFO
>   [08-25|21:14:29] Submitted transaction
>   fullhash=0x33ca6bb00a70de13bd8b1fdec5d0a7995ad09a90e416ac8ab686fc650a324331
>   recipient=0x939f34bc9253a62927871c889bcf62f398d264a6 INFO
>   [08-25|21:14:57] Updated mining threads                   threads=1
>   INFO [08-25|21:14:57] Transaction pool price threshold updated
>   price=18000000000 INFO [08-25|21:14:57] Starting mining operation 
>   INFO [08-25|21:14:57] Commit new mining work
>   number=1 txs=2 uncles=0 elapsed=73.574ms

But when i run

```
eth.pendingTransactions
```

i am able to see the list of above sent transactions
 SO my question is 
When will the transactions be mined?

P.S.- i am running it on my local machine(private blockchain)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you don't find help here maybe you'll have better luck at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: did you unlock eth.accounts[0]?

Comment: Yes the account is unlocked. I did that before.
One notable thing i found is when i run `mining.start(1)` it is returning **null** Can that be the root of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using private blockchain then you can run `miner.start()` function using the console. After that it will take 5-6 min and miner will be ready to pick your transaction and automatically coinbase account balance will be increased.

Some time if you send very less gas and gasprice with your transaction with your transaction then may be transaction gets stuck. So please send enough gas with your transaction. It will get executed.

You can also send gas and gasprice in your command as below--

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.coinbase, to: "0x154230ed91d1e711e56b9c0f88b5ba5fd2bghjgf", value: web3.toWei(5, "ether"),gas:21000,gasPrice:web3.toWei(45,"wei")})
```

Hope this will help